# Visible differences between Material UI and Material 2 Design?

Tags: material-ui, material-design

There is a 79$ Figma version of MUI components sold through https://mui.com/store/#design
(a free demo version seems to be available).

And there is a free version of Material 2 Design Components available through
https://www.figma.com/community/file/778763161265841481

If I understood it right, MUI is simply implementing M2, so why would I pay for the MUI resources, when the M2 version should be the same and is for free? Are there any visible differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's my personal take on the difference. You are correct that MUI is a component library that implements Material Design 2 standards.

The community Material 2 Design kit is an official Figma kit from the Material Design Team intended to get you started. It has not been maintained since October 27, 2021. Depending on your design needs, this may be sufficient.

The premium MUI for Figma UI kit is built by the team that creates the MUI library. Its intended to deliver a full design kit for the entire MUI library including their custom components an customization options that are not a part of the Material Design 2 standard. Also, this kit is maintained and being kept up to date with their actual react components.

It is very likely you will find differences in design between the two kits, but at times they may be subtle. You'd need to open the two side by side and analyze a component to really identify the difference in design implementation in MUI compared to the Material 2 Design components kit.

If you're designing for an application that is being built using MUI, you'll have the option of saving yourself a lot of time using their kit instead of building the components in Figma yourself. In theory, this should also help the Developer Handoff because the final design in Figma should be nearly identical to what the developers implement using MUI. The developers won't have to question if a difference between the design and implementation is simply a difference in the MUI library or if its a missing design requirement.

I would absolutely buy the MUI for Figma kit if my development team was going to be using the MUI library. That said, I haven't actually checked out the MUI figma kit, so I would certainly recommend testing out their free preview version first to ensure it meets your needs before purchasing. Looks like a solid kit from the overview though.

*Note: I chose RMWC over MUI a few years ago so its been a while since I reviewed MUI.*